# Pass type parameter through several derived classes for using in generic static constructor

Tags: c#, generics

I have some generic template for multiton or objects pool.

```
public class A<TC> where TC : class, new()
{
    protected static ConcurrentDictionary<object, TC> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, TC>();

    public static TC Instance(object key)
    {
        return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new TC());
    }
}

// One level inheritance works as expected    

public class B : A<B> 
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}

// Class C is example of what I want    
// How to override method from B, pass C to A and use it in GetInstance?

public class C : B<C>
{
    public override int Demo() { return 2; }
}
```

**Question** : I want class C to override method from B, how can I pass type parameter "C" through the chain of child classes to use it with method Instance() from A, is it possible at all?

I tried to modify B but seems that it makes it generic and does not allow to instantiate B :

```
public class B<TC> : A<TC> where TC : class, new()
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}
```

**Update** : the idea is to have generic static constructor, then I derive class Memory from it that works with memory mapped files, but this class can read and write only bytes sequence in and out, thus, I create class MemoryStructs derived from Memory and this class can read and write whole structures, of course, **I can put all these methods into Memory but I thought it may be useful to split them logically, thus, I have such inheritance chain : BaseClass > Memory > MemoryStructs**

Memory and MemoryStructs classes have method OpenMemory and CloseMemory and I'm not willing to duplicate those methods for each of them, thus I need either :

- inherit MemoryStructs from Memory as I am trying now or
- put all methods into Memory class naming them ReadBytes (Memory) and ReadStructs (MemoryStructs)

Comment: What's the reason for needing `C` to be derived from `B`? Many-layered inheritance is a poisoned chalice and so you are better off avoiding it if possible.

Comment: @David Arno : the idea is to have generic static constructor, then I derive class Memory from it that works with memory mapped files, but this class can read and write only bytes sequence in and out, thus, I create class MemoryStructs derived from Memory and this class can read and write whole structures ... of course, I can put all these methods into Memory but I thought it may be useful to split them logically, thus, I have such inheritance chain : BaseClass > Memory > MemoryStructs

Comment: Side note: what you describe seem to be `Stream`/`StreamReader` pair of classes and similarly to that pair your classes likely should not be derived one from another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need another class in the chain?

```
public class B1<T> : A<B1<T>> 
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}
public class B2 : B1<B2>
{
    // Something that C does not do
}
public class C : B1<C>
{
   public override int Demo() { return 2; }
}
```

**Edit:**

Seems like that you want to inherit some functionality of B and pass a type argument to it in C meanwhile you want to define B as a non-generic class, that's not possible, B must be either non-generic that you don't have C : B<C> anymore:

```
public class B : A<B>
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}
public class C : B
{
   public override int Demo() { return 2; }
}
```

or it must be generic so you can't pass B as a type argument to A:

```
public class B<T> : A<T>
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}
public class C : B<T>
{
   public override int Demo() { return 2; }
}
```

or you may choose to use the composition pattern and create an instance of B in C so that you can use it's functionality in C:

```
public class B : A<B>
{
    public virtual int Demo() { return 1; }
}
public class C : A<C>
{
   private B b = new B();
   public override int Demo() {
      // Maybe use b here
      return 2;
   }
}
```

Comment: ah, wait, sorry, cannot accept it for now, idea is good, so I upvoted, but when I try to add "override" to "C" compiler says that Demo() is not found, in some reason B1.Demo is not visible for C.Demo even though C is inherited from B1, I believe this suggestion is closest to what I need but I need to tweak it a bit

Comment: @Art I edited the answer before you accept but saw you accepted the previous one, then I rolled the edit back, I edit it again.

Comment: Decided that easiest way is to keep all memory methods in one class and have only one level inheritance : A > B

Comment: @Art avoiding multiple inheritance as much as possible helps a lot to reduce complexity. I think you did the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

`Instance` is a static method of `A<TC>` so there does not even exist an `Instance` method in `B` which you could override (even if you could, the `TC` type parameter would be bound to `B` by then, so a method returning `C` would be a different method).

So the way you call `Instance` is using `A<TC>.Instance(key)` where `TC` is an actual type. So for example:

```
B objectB = A<B>.Instance(key)
C objectC = A<C>.Instance(key)
```

Note that the concurrent dictionary is separate *for each* type parameter `TC`, so `A<B>` and `A<C>` do *not* share the same dictionary; they are different types with separate static members.

Comment: Yes, I could instantiate them this way but in this case B and C needs to be both derived from A which means that some similar methods in these classes may be duplicated, e.g. B works with memory in bytes and C works with it in structures and they both have methods OpenMemory and CloseMemory

Comment: My point is that `Instance` is static, so it's not being inherited at all. It only belongs to A.

Comment: yes, Instance() is static and cannot be inherited, we simply need to pass T from C to A somehow to make Instance working properly, we can do this when we are declaring new class - B : A<C> { ... }, inheritance is needed for another method - Demo()

Answer (score 1):

@David Amo is absolutely correct. Maybe this is what you are after?

```
public abstract class A<TC> where TC : class, new()
{
    protected static ConcurrentDictionary<object, TC> _instances = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<object, TC>();

    public static TC Instance(object key)
    {
        return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new TC());
    }

    public abstract int Demo();
}

public class B : A<B>
{
    public override int Demo() { return 1; }
}

public class C : A<C>
{
    public override int Demo() { return 2; }
}
```

Comment: Well, I could do it this way but this will force me to duplicate similar methods in B and C ... I added update to my question